# add shadow to the UIView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview

I want to add shadow to the every cell of [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwkm7.png)
for that i added a UIView,but how can I customize,and where to write the code to customize it,the UIView is in a cellView of a tableView

the code

```
let profil = ["Eric","Eric","Eric","Eric","Eric","Eric"]

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return(profil.count)
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ListOffersViewControllerTableViewCell

    cell.profilName.text = profil[indexPath.row]

    return(cell)

}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .white
    cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0


}
```

I connected the UIView like that the other cocoa touch class

```
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundCardView: UIView!
```

but i don't know how to use it

EDIT

the new [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFeY2.png)
I need to have some space between the cells to as to have something like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIPeN.png)

Comment: you need to add shadows inside cell code. add some code of ListOffersViewControllerTableViewCell

Comment: and you need to add shadows to face image? oval frame?

Comment: sorry @SergeyHleb i didn't get you point

Comment: I added the UIView so as to this shadow effect at the corners of every cell

Comment: how can i add the code inside the cell code?I think I should declare a variable related to the UIView name because when I try to write `backgroundCardView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0` they don't recognize backgroundCardView

Comment: ListOffersViewControllerTableViewCell - it's your Cell's class. now I don't understand what are you need? corner radius or shadows?

Comment: shadows,i just gave you an example to show that i don't know how to edit the UIView
and yeah ListOffersViewControllerTableViewCell is the name of the cell's class

Comment: can you help Mr @SergeyHleb

Comment: check my answer, is that what you need?

Comment: nope,i added a comment on your answer,please check it

Comment: and? do you check this?

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:
here example code of cell's Class

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    func setText(text: String) {
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: 0, height: 0)
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false;
        self.clipsToBounds = false;
        label.text = text
    }
}
```

And here result:
 [image: Screenshot]

You can changes this values like you need for achieve some result.
**Update**
1. add this method to your ListOffersViewControllerTableViewCell Class

```
func setShadows() {
            self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: 0, height: 0)
            self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            self.layer.shadowRadius = 5
            self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
            self.layer.masksToBounds = false;
            self.clipsToBounds = false;
        }
```

2. edit your tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell method like this:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ListOffersViewControllerTableViewCell
    cell.setShadows()
    cell.profilName.text = profil[indexPath.row]
    return(cell)

}
```

**Update**

do this simple steps:
1. on your storyBoard add subView to your cell.
2. put all of your content on this subView.
3. height of this subView must be, for example, less than cell's height by 10.
4. connect IBOutlet property of this view to your cell's Class.
5. edit setShadows method like this:

```
func setShadows() {
                self.myView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: 0, height: 0)
                self.myView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                self.myView.layer.shadowRadius = 5
                self.myView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
                self.myView.layer.masksToBounds = false;
                self.myView.clipsToBounds = false;
            }
```

where myView - UIView, which you added on storyboard and connected to your cell's Class.
And here result:
[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: you needn't for some View, you can set shadows for cell

Comment: i don't know how to do it ,I tried
`cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear cell.contentView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor cell.contentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0) cell.contentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0 cell.contentView.layer.shadowRadius = 2`

but it was applied to the content inside the cell not the cell

Comment: I added 2 steps. check it and write about result

Comment: It worked but i there is no space between cells,how can I add it? I can upload an screenshot of the app if you want

Comment: let upload it to your question

Comment: in that way you need to add subview to cell, for example with height less than cell height by 10 and set shadows for that view, but not for cell. do you understand how to do this?

Comment: I don't know how to do it, I'm beginner

Answer (score 0):

My UIView Extension - That Add Border and Shadow Effect

```
extension UIView
{
    func roundCornerWithBorderForTableView()
    {
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0/255, green:96/255, blue:114/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10        
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.clipsToBounds = false
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    }
}
```

Usage For the Extension:

```
class tableCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var baseView: UIView!{
        didSet{
            baseView.roundCornerWithBorderForTableView()
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var textValue: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Just Need to add a new View as Subview in The main Content View Using StoryBoard 
as Like

View Hierarchy :
[image]

BaseView Constraints : View which will be used to create Shadow Effect and Border
[image]

Constraints:

[image]

Sample Code - https://drive.google.com/file/d/13VhiFYf9QC-ToJ6Wk6FYPM5tPthdXaFC/view?usp=sharing

Output ScreenShot 
[image]

Comment: I only have Xcode 8 so the file can't be open,the problem is that i can't add a contraints to the view i don't know why?I've already put the border and shadow code in the cell code not the view as shown in the first answer,how can you help me now?

Comment: how are you addiing tableviews , programatically ? and I will suggest you to download Xcode 9

Comment: Do you have options in your Xcode 8 StoryBoard like I have Use AutoLayout constraints  ![screen shot 2018-04-19 at 9 45 29 am](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/26831784/38971008-750f67a8-43b6-11e8-83e6-9c4e4dd84737.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have create function for view shadow:-

```
func addShadow(view: UIView, corner: CGFloat) {
    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
    view.layer.masksToBounds = false
    view.layer.cornerRadius = corner
}
```